# ePub Reader Application using cordova

Tags: cordova, epub

I am trying to create an ePub reader application using Cordova. Also I'd like to use the turn.js plugin in my application. Please suggest me some ideas to start this application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an open-ended question, but here are a few tips:

- Think about how you will be getting the .epub files. An open or closed cloud service? Project Gutenberg? From the local device? Each service will have its pros and cons.
- Since cordova is just a w3c widget implementation, you'll want to find an [.epub reader library written in HTML / javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933086/how-to-read-epub-files-using-javascript).
- From your desire to use turn.js, it sounds like the layout is important to you. You'll want to note that not all .epub readers are created equal. Test some real .epub files with embedded fonts, etc., to make sure they'll render properly. Some of the readers gave me fits when I worked on .epub exports for a project.
- Another thing to note -- if you're new to Cordova -- it's not very opinionated in what javascript frameworks you use. [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) and [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) are a couple options -- there are others out there.
- I started with tutorials and webinars from Christophe Coenraets [like this one](https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/) to get my feet wet with Cordova. Your mileage may vary; this was a couple years ago and I'm not sure how up to date this is now.